# How to get the geo location using amp-geo on an amp page

Tags: amp-html

We are trying to retrieve the Geo location from the visitors on our AMP pages. And we have added the script `<script async custom-element="amp-geo" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-geo-0.1.js"></script>` to the head. And in the body `<amp-geo layout="nodisplay"></amp-geo>`.

And we have created a analytics vendor and all the data gets returned in the url of the analytics action except for the ${ampGeo} as documented [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-var-substitutions.md#amp-components).

Do we need to add more or what is wrong?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: What more do you want to know, it is just an example page in amp.